# Quaternion relative error measurement

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions

So, for the last couple of days I have been trying to implement different means of data compression, primarily related to algebraic entities. In order to evaluate the result (primarily precision loss) I have been relying on calculating the relative error.

Now, doing so for standard linear algebra constructs such as a matrix or vector is no problem but I have run into somewhat of a snag when it comes to quaternions. Is there a standard measurement of relative error when it comes to quaternions? Now I am forced to convert the quaternions to matrices and calculate their relative error... which isn't really the same thing.

Would it be viable to adapt the standard vector approach to quaternions?.. seeing as they are kind of like 4D vectors?

Any thoughts on this would be welcome! :)
-Maigo

Answer (score 0):

For quaternions a [norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuaternionNorm.html) is defined: you can measure errors and distances in this norm. Fortunately enough this norm coincides with the euclidean norm for 4D real vectors, so you can simply take the squadre root of the sum of the squared components.

[Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Norm.html) more info on norms.

Answer (score 0):

When the quaternions are unit-length, (e.g., as when they are being used to represent rotations/orientations) then it's common to compare them by measuring the angle between the them.  Use the absolute value of the dot-product of the two quaternions.  With unit length quaternions, you'll get a value from 0 to 1.  'Zero' means that they're as different as they can be.  'One' means that they're the same rotation.